# ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module ../node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3,

Tags: angular, firebase

ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/projects/youtube-angular/firestore-app/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3,

I have never seen this. I tried to uninstall everything and reinstall to newest versions and still getting that error. No one else running the project seems to have this issue. So i am guessing that is some local setting or install i have wrong but can't figure this one out.

```
package.json
{
  "name": "firestore-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried completely deleting your node_modules folder and clean install? sounds like a lingering old module installed possibly.  Could also try to clean out any npm cache you have going https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Comment: Ya i just started a new project (ng new ...)then copied exact same code over, then npm installed angularfire2 and works fine....not sure what happened but agree something didn't install properly. thanks for your reply.

Comment: This thing is not intermittent or environment issue for me, notably it happening while calling `AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools ` inside `@ngtools/webpack`. Secondly it happens on server launch only, if I make some code change and allow server to auto refresh I don't see it.

Comment: I had exact same issue in my angular app. My [resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694285/8680456) is posted in here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same problem but solved it by changing the release candidate  on angularfire2 back to 3  like `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3"` from  `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"` in your package.json file. then delete node modules and run `npm i or npm install`.

Or you can unintall angularfire2 make sure you also remove it from your package.json and package.json.lock files. reinstall it and specify the release candidate like `npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save`.

Comment: second option worked for me. Run `npm uninstall angularfire2` before you run given command!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to change the cli version and the angularfire2 version too

```
npm install @angular/cli@ version 1.2.1 --save

npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
```

Comment: In my case, I didn't need to downgrade @angular/cli, I just execute       " npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save   " that can add other packages as well

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and it didn't work. The only answer that help me was to update all @angular packages like @angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/compiler-cli, "@angular/core, etc to latest versions (5.1.1).

After that I also need to update rxjs to latest (5.5.5).

Than is compiled successfully with --prod.