# Angular 4, angularfire2, Metadata version mismatch

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've got the following error

> Metadata version mismatch for module c:/..../node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version4, expected 3.

And if I go and check in my **package.json**, I have angularfire2 on version 5.0.0-rc.4, and firebase on 4.6.2.
[see screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdFoS.png)

I tried changing the version of angularfire2 and firebase to previous versions but nothing worked.

Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

```
{
  "name": "twitter-revamped",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "ng2-semantic-ui": "^0.9.6",
    "rxjs": "<5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it

Had to set firebase and angularfire2 to this:

`"firebase":"4.6.0",
"angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3"`

but then I got another error:
 `"@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'`

A npm install fixed it.

Comment: what version of angular are you using? Do you mind sharing your package.json ?

Comment: new error occur after doing this,
> firebaseui-angular.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Answer (score 22):

I tried above solutions but it didn't solve my issue. I tried the below steps & it solved my issue.

The issue actually occurred when `npm install angularfire2 firebase --save` command was run. Below dependencies were added in package.json

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"firebase": "^4.7.0"
```

Actual issue here is due to the version of **angularfire2**. We need to have **angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3** instead of **angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4**. I am not aware as to why this version is having issue.

Below are the steps for resolution:

**STEP 1: Uninstall angularfire2 & firebase**

```
npm uninstall angularfire2 firebase --save
```

**STEP 2: Install angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.3 version**

```
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
```

**STEP 3: Install firebase**

```
npm install firebase --save
```

**STEP 4: Check dependencies added in package.json**

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"firebase": "^4.7.0"
```

**STEP 5: Execute ng serve**

```
ng serve
```

This solves the issue & application compiles successfully.

Comment: I tried this solution, did not work for the first time. Noticed the firebase version was 4.8.1. Again uninstalled this version and installed 4.7.0 version. Cleared my npm cache and it started working.. Thanks..

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved this problem. Follow the steps as i have listed:

**STEP 1: Uninstall previous angularfire2 installed pacakge**

`npm uninstall angularfire2`

**STEP 2: Install angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.3**

`npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save`

**STEP 3: Check your package.json**

Make sure you have the following lines under dependencies in package.json

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
"firebase": "^4.6.0",
```

This is how i solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem but solved it by changing the release candidate  on angularfire2 back to 3  like `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3"` from  `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4"` in your package.json file. then delete node modules and run `npm i or npm install`.

Or you can unintall angularfire2 make sure you also remove it from your package.json and package.json.lock files. reinstall it and specify the release candidate like `npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save`.

Answer (score 0):

angularfire2 *5.0.0-rc.4* should work with firebase *4.5.0* and angular *5.0.0*

Check [angularfire2 package.json](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/5.0.0-rc.4/package.json) :

```
"firebase": "^4.5.0"
```

Comment: Upgrade angular from 4.2.4 to 5.0.0

Comment: Same Problem please help.!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Downgrade the angularfire2's version to "5.0.0-rc.3" worked with me.

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps - will be solved the problem 
1. npm uninstall angularfire2 firebase --save
2. npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
3. npm install firebase --save
4. ng serve

Answer (score 0):

This error occured to me as well when I do `ng serve` after `yarn upgarde` that installed:

```
  angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.5-next
  firebase@4.13.1
```

Downgrading to `angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3` solved the problem:

```
  yarn remove angularfire2
  yarn add angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3
```

`angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4` didn't work with new `firabase`, not feeling right to see this type of endless upgrade trouble.