# Angular 4+ Firebase Visual Sutudio Online Azure CI build error

Tags: angular, azure, firebase, azure-pipelines

I have an application that is already published to Azure using VSO CI process. After a few months, I am pushing some minor changes and the build kicks off but the build fails with the following error (please see the full log below):

"Metadata version mismatch for module D:/a/1/s/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3[39m[22m[0m"

Further to mention, in my local machine I can run the "ng build --prod" and everything works fine. Somehow the Visual Studio Online build fails.

Also, I have followed the suggestions on [Angular 4, angularfire2, Metadata version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441625/angular-4-angularfire2-metadata-version-mismatch/47441777) and couple of other links. I have also upgraded my Angular-Cli to latests but no success.

Does anyone know what is going on?

```
| | | | `-- ieee754@1.1.11 
| | | +-- console-browserify@1.1.0 
| | | | `-- date-now@0.1.4 
| | | +-- constants-browserify@1.0.0 
| | | +-- crypto-browserify@3.12.0 
| | | | +-- browserify-cipher@1.0.1 
| | | | | +-- browserify-aes@1.2.0 
| | | | | | `-- buffer-xor@1.0.3 
| | | | | +-- browserify-des@1.0.1 
| | | | | | `-- des.js@1.0.0 
| | | | | `-- evp_bytestokey@1.0.3 
| | | | +-- browserify-sign@4.0.4 
| | | | | +-- bn.js@4.11.8 
| | | | | +-- browserify-rsa@4.0.1 
| | | | | +-- elliptic@6.4.0 
| | | | | | +-- brorand@1.1.0 
| | | | | | +-- hash.js@1.1.3 
| | | | | | +-- hmac-drbg@1.0.1 
| | | | | | `-- minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1 
| | | | | `-- parse-asn1@5.1.1 
| | | | |   `-- asn1.js@4.10.1 
| | | | +-- create-ecdh@4.0.1 
| | | | +-- create-hash@1.2.0 
| | | | | +-- cipher-base@1.0.4 
| | | | | +-- md5.js@1.3.4 
| | | | | | `-- hash-base@3.0.4 
| | | | | +-- ripemd160@2.0.2 
| | | | | `-- sha.js@2.4.11 
| | | | +-- create-hmac@1.1.7 
| | | | +-- diffie-hellman@5.0.3 
| | | | | `-- miller-rabin@4.0.1 
| | | | +-- pbkdf2@3.0.16 
| | | | +-- public-encrypt@4.0.2 
| | | | +-- randombytes@2.0.6 
| | | | `-- randomfill@1.0.4 
| | | +-- domain-browser@1.2.0 
| | | +-- events@1.1.1 
| | | +-- https-browserify@1.0.0 
| | | +-- os-browserify@0.3.0 
| | | +-- path-browserify@0.0.0 
| | | +-- process@0.11.10 
| | | +-- punycode@1.4.1 
| | | +-- querystring-es3@0.2.1 
| | | +-- stream-browserify@2.0.1 
| | | +-- stream-http@2.8.1 
| | | | +-- builtin-status-codes@3.0.0 
| | | | +-- to-arraybuffer@1.0.1 
| | | | `-- xtend@4.0.1 
| | | +-- timers-browserify@2.0.10 
| | | | `-- setimmediate@1.0.5 
| | | +-- tty-browserify@0.0.0 
| | | +-- url@0.11.0 
| | | | +-- punycode@1.3.2 
| | | | `-- querystring@0.2.0 
| | | +-- util@0.10.3 
| | | | `-- inherits@2.0.1 
| | | `-- vm-browserify@0.0.4 
| | +-- tapable@0.2.8 
| | +-- uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 
| | | `-- uglify-js@2.8.29 
| | |   +-- uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
| | |   `-- yargs@3.10.0 
| | |     +-- camelcase@1.2.1 
| | |     +-- cliui@2.1.0 
| | |     | +-- center-align@0.1.3 
| | |     | | +-- align-text@0.1.4 
| | |     | | | `-- longest@1.0.1 
| | |     | | `-- lazy-cache@1.0.4 
| | |     `-- window-size@0.1.0 
| | +-- watchpack@1.6.0 
| | | `-- chokidar@2.0.3 
| | |   +-- anymatch@2.0.0 
| | |   | `-- micromatch@3.1.10 
| | |   |   +-- arr-diff@4.0.0 
| | |   |   +-- extglob@2.0.4 
| | |   |   | +-- define-property@1.0.0 
| | |   |   | | `-- is-descriptor@1.0.2 
| | |   |   | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | |   |   | |   `-- is-data-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | |   |   | +-- expand-brackets@2.1.4 
| | |   |   | | +-- define-property@0.2.5 
| | |   |   | | | `-- is-descriptor@0.1.6 
| | |   |   | | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@0.1.6 
| | |   |   | | |   | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | |   |   | | |   +-- is-data-descriptor@0.1.4 
| | |   |   | | |   | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | |   |   | | |   `-- kind-of@5.1.0 
| | |   |   | | `-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | |   |   | `-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | |   |   `-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | |   +-- braces@2.3.2 
| | |   | +-- array-unique@0.3.2 
| | |   | +-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | |   | +-- fill-range@4.0.0 
| | |   | | +-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | |   | | `-- is-number@3.0.0 
| | |   | |   `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | |   | `-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | |   +-- glob-parent@3.1.0 
| | |   | `-- is-glob@3.1.0 
| | |   `-- is-glob@4.0.0 
| | |     `-- is-extglob@2.1.1 
| | `-- yargs@8.0.2 
| |   +-- camelcase@4.1.0 
| |   +-- cliui@3.2.0 
| |   | +-- string-width@1.0.2 
| |   | `-- wrap-ansi@2.1.0 
| |   +-- get-caller-file@1.0.2 
| |   +-- os-locale@2.1.0 
| |   | +-- execa@0.7.0 
| |   | | +-- cross-spawn@5.1.0 
| |   | | | `-- shebang-command@1.2.0 
| |   | | |   `-- shebang-regex@1.0.0 
| |   | | +-- get-stream@3.0.0 
| |   | | +-- npm-run-path@2.0.2 
| |   | | | `-- path-key@2.0.1 
| |   | | +-- p-finally@1.0.0 
| |   | | `-- strip-eof@1.0.0 
| |   | +-- lcid@1.0.0 
| |   | | `-- invert-kv@1.0.0 
| |   | `-- mem@1.1.0 
| |   |   `-- mimic-fn@1.2.0 
| |   +-- read-pkg-up@2.0.0 
| |   | `-- read-pkg@2.0.0 
| |   |   +-- load-json-file@2.0.0 
| |   |   | +-- pify@2.3.0 
| |   |   | `-- strip-bom@3.0.0 
| |   |   `-- path-type@2.0.0 
| |   +-- require-directory@2.1.1 
| |   +-- require-main-filename@1.0.1 
| |   +-- string-width@2.1.1 
| |   | +-- is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 
| |   | `-- strip-ansi@4.0.0 
| |   |   `-- ansi-regex@3.0.0 
| |   +-- which-module@2.0.0 
| |   +-- y18n@3.2.1 
| |   `-- yargs-parser@7.0.0 
| |     `-- camelcase@4.1.0 
| +-- webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 
| | `-- time-stamp@2.0.0 
| +-- webpack-dev-server@2.11.2 
| | +-- ansi-html@0.0.7 
| | +-- array-includes@3.0.3 
| | | +-- define-properties@1.1.2 
| | | | +-- foreach@2.0.5 
| | | | `-- object-keys@1.0.11 
| | | `-- es-abstract@1.11.0 
| | |   +-- es-to-primitive@1.1.1 
| | |   | +-- is-date-object@1.0.1 
| | |   | `-- is-symbol@1.0.1 
| | |   +-- function-bind@1.1.1 
| | |   +-- has@1.0.1 
| | |   +-- is-callable@1.1.3 
| | |   `-- is-regex@1.0.4 
| | +-- bonjour@3.5.0 
| | | +-- array-flatten@2.1.1 
| | | +-- deep-equal@1.0.1 
| | | +-- dns-equal@1.0.0 
| | | +-- dns-txt@2.0.2 
| | | | `-- buffer-indexof@1.1.1 
| | | +-- multicast-dns@6.2.3 
| | | | +-- dns-packet@1.3.1 
| | | | `-- thunky@1.0.2 
| | | `-- multicast-dns-service-types@1.1.0 
| | +-- chokidar@2.0.3 
| | | +-- anymatch@2.0.0 
| | | | `-- micromatch@3.1.10 
| | | |   +-- arr-diff@4.0.0 
| | | |   | +-- is-descriptor@1.0.2 
| | | |   | | +-- is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | |   | | +-- is-data-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | |   | | `-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | | |   | `-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | |   +-- extend-shallow@3.0.2 
| | | |   | +-- assign-symbols@1.0.0 
| | | |   | `-- is-extendable@1.0.1 
| | | |   +-- extglob@2.0.4 
| | | |   | +-- define-property@1.0.0 
| | | |   | | `-- is-descriptor@1.0.2 
| | | |   | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | |   | |   `-- is-data-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | |   | +-- expand-brackets@2.1.4 
| | | |   | | +-- debug@2.6.9 
| | | |   | | +-- define-property@0.2.5 
| | | |   | | | `-- is-descriptor@0.1.6 
| | | |   | | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@0.1.6 
| | | |   | | |   | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | | |   | | |   +-- is-data-descriptor@0.1.4 
| | | |   | | |   | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | | |   | | |   `-- kind-of@5.1.0 
| | | |   | | +-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | |   | | `-- posix-character-classes@0.1.1 
| | | |   | `-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | |   +-- fragment-cache@0.2.1 
| | | |   +-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | | |   +-- nanomatch@1.2.9 
| | | |   | +-- arr-diff@4.0.0 
| | | |   | +-- array-unique@0.3.2 
| | | |   | +-- is-odd@2.0.0 
| | | |   | | `-- is-number@4.0.0 
| | | |   | +-- is-windows@1.0.2 
| | | |   | `-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | | |   +-- object.pick@1.3.0 
| | | |   | `-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | |   `-- regex-not@1.0.2 
| | | +-- braces@2.3.2 
| | | | +-- arr-flatten@1.1.0 
| | | | +-- array-unique@0.3.2 
| | | | +-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | | +-- fill-range@4.0.0 
| | | | | +-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | | | +-- is-number@3.0.0 
| | | | | | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | | | | +-- repeat-string@1.6.1 
| | | | | `-- to-regex-range@2.1.1 
| | | | |   `-- is-number@3.0.0 
| | | | +-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | +-- repeat-element@1.1.2 
| | | | +-- snapdragon@0.8.2 
| | | | | +-- base@0.11.2 
| | | | | | +-- cache-base@1.0.1 
| | | | | | | +-- collection-visit@1.0.0 
| | | | | | | | +-- map-visit@1.0.0 
| | | | | | | | `-- object-visit@1.0.1 
| | | | | | | |   `-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | | | +-- get-value@2.0.6 
| | | | | | | +-- has-value@1.0.0 
| | | | | | | | +-- has-values@1.0.0 
| | | | | | | | | +-- is-number@3.0.0 
| | | | | | | | | | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | | | | | | | | `-- kind-of@4.0.0 
| | | | | | | | `-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | | | +-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | | | +-- set-value@2.0.0 
| | | | | | | | `-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | | | | | +-- to-object-path@0.3.0 
| | | | | | | +-- union-value@1.0.0 
| | | | | | | | `-- set-value@0.4.3 
| | | | | | | |   `-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | | | | | `-- unset-value@1.0.0 
| | | | | | |   +-- has-value@0.3.1 
| | | | | | |   | +-- has-values@0.1.4 
| | | | | | |   | `-- isobject@2.1.0 
| | | | | | |   `-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | | +-- class-utils@0.3.6 
| | | | | | | +-- arr-union@3.1.0 
| | | | | | | +-- define-property@0.2.5 
| | | | | | | +-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | | | `-- static-extend@0.1.2 
| | | | | | |   +-- define-property@0.2.5 
| | | | | | |   `-- object-copy@0.1.0 
| | | | | | |     +-- copy-descriptor@0.1.1 
| | | | | | |     `-- define-property@0.2.5 
| | | | | | +-- define-property@1.0.0 
| | | | | | | `-- is-descriptor@1.0.2 
| | | | | | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | | | | |   +-- is-data-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | | | | |   `-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | | | | | +-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | | +-- mixin-deep@1.3.1 
| | | | | | | `-- is-extendable@1.0.1 
| | | | | | `-- pascalcase@0.1.1 
| | | | | +-- define-property@0.2.5 
| | | | | | `-- is-descriptor@0.1.6 
| | | | | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@0.1.6 
| | | | | |   +-- is-data-descriptor@0.1.4 
| | | | | |   `-- kind-of@5.1.0 
| | | | | +-- extend-shallow@2.0.1 
| | | | | +-- source-map-resolve@0.5.1 
| | | | | | +-- atob@2.1.1 
| | | | | | +-- decode-uri-component@0.2.0 
| | | | | | +-- resolve-url@0.2.1 
| | | | | | +-- source-map-url@0.4.0 
| | | | | | `-- urix@0.1.0 
| | | | | `-- use@3.1.0 
| | | | |   `-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | | | +-- snapdragon-node@2.1.1 
| | | | | +-- define-property@1.0.0 
| | | | | | `-- is-descriptor@1.0.2 
| | | | | |   +-- is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | | | |   +-- is-data-descriptor@1.0.0 
| | | | | |   `-- kind-of@6.0.2 
| | | | | +-- isobject@3.0.1 
| | | | | `-- snapdragon-util@3.0.1 
| | | | +-- split-string@3.1.0 
| | | | `-- to-regex@3.0.2 
| | | |   `-- safe-regex@1.1.0 
| | | |     `-- ret@0.1.15 
| | | +-- glob-parent@3.1.0 
| | | | +-- is-glob@3.1.0 
| | | | `-- path-dirname@1.0.2 
| | | +-- is-glob@4.0.0 
| | | | `-- is-extglob@2.1.1 
| | | +-- normalize-path@2.1.1 
| | | | `-- remove-trailing-separator@1.1.0 
| | | `-- upath@1.0.5 
| | +-- compression@1.7.2 
| | | +-- accepts@1.3.5 
| | | | `-- negotiator@0.6.1 
| | | +-- compressible@2.0.13 
| | | +-- on-headers@1.0.1 
| | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.1 
| | | `-- vary@1.1.2 
| | +-- connect-history-api-fallback@1.5.0 
| | +-- debug@3.1.0 
| | +-- del@3.0.0 
| | | +-- globby@6.1.0 
| | | | `-- pify@2.3.0 
| | | +-- is-path-cwd@1.0.0 
| | | +-- is-path-in-cwd@1.0.1 
| | | | `-- is-path-inside@1.0.1 
| | | |   `-- path-is-inside@1.0.2 
| | | `-- p-map@1.2.0 
| | +-- express@4.16.3 
| | | +-- array-flatten@1.1.1 
| | | +-- content-disposition@0.5.2 
| | | +-- cookie@0.3.1 
| | | +-- cookie-signature@1.0.6 
| | | +-- encodeurl@1.0.2 
| | | +-- escape-html@1.0.3 
| | | +-- etag@1.8.1 
| | | +-- finalhandler@1.1.1 
| | | +-- fresh@0.5.2 
| | | +-- merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
| | | +-- methods@1.1.2 
| | | +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
| | | +-- proxy-addr@2.0.3 
| | | | +-- forwarded@0.1.2 
| | | | `-- ipaddr.js@1.6.0 
| | | +-- qs@6.5.1 
| | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.1 
| | | +-- send@0.16.2 
| | | | +-- destroy@1.0.4 
| | | | `-- mime@1.4.1 
| | | +-- serve-static@1.13.2 
| | | +-- setprototypeof@1.1.0 
| | | `-- statuses@1.4.0 
| | +-- html-entities@1.2.1 
| | +-- http-proxy-middleware@0.17.4 
| | | +-- is-glob@3.1.0 
| | | | `-- is-extglob@2.1.1 
| | | `-- micromatch@2.3.11 
| | |   +-- arr-diff@2.0.0 
| | |   +-- braces@1.8.5 
| | |   | +-- expand-range@1.8.2 
| | |   | | `-- fill-range@2.2.3 
| | |   | |   +-- is-number@2.1.0 
| | |   | |   +-- isobject@2.1.0 
| | |   | |   `-- randomatic@1.1.7 
| | |   | |     +-- is-number@3.0.0 
| | |   | |     | `-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | |   | |     `-- kind-of@4.0.0 
| | |   | `-- preserve@0.2.0 
| | |   +-- expand-brackets@0.1.5 
| | |   | `-- is-posix-bracket@0.1.1 
| | |   +-- extglob@0.3.2 
| | |   +-- filename-regex@2.0.1 
| | |   +-- kind-of@3.2.2 
| | |   | `-- is-buffer@1.1.6 
| | |   +-- object.omit@2.0.1 
| | |   | `-- for-own@0.1.5 
| | |   +-- parse-glob@3.0.4 
| | |   | +-- glob-base@0.3.0 
| | |   | `-- is-dotfile@1.0.3 
| | |   `-- regex-cache@0.4.4 
| | |     `-- is-equal-shallow@0.1.3 
| | |       `-- is-primitive@2.0.0 
| | +-- import-local@1.0.0 
| | |   `-- resolve-from@3.0.0 
| | +-- internal-ip@1.2.0 
| | +-- ip@1.1.5 
| | +-- killable@1.0.0 
| | +-- loglevel@1.6.1 
| | +-- selfsigned@1.10.2 
| | | `-- node-forge@0.7.1 
| | +-- serve-index@1.9.1 
| | | `-- batch@0.6.1 
| | +-- sockjs@0.3.19 
| | | `-- faye-websocket@0.10.0 
| | +-- sockjs-client@1.1.4 
| | | +-- eventsource@0.1.6 
| | | | `-- original@1.0.0 
| | | |   `-- url-parse@1.0.5 
| | | |     `-- querystringify@0.0.4 
| | | +-- json3@3.3.2 
| | | `-- url-parse@1.4.0 
| | |   `-- querystringify@2.0.0 
| | +-- spdy@3.4.7 
| | | +-- handle-thing@1.2.5 
| | | +-- http-deceiver@1.2.7 
| | | +-- select-hose@2.0.0 
| | | `-- spdy-transport@2.1.0 
| | |   +-- detect-node@2.0.3 
| | |   +-- hpack.js@2.1.6 
| | |   +-- obuf@1.1.2 
| | |   `-- wbuf@1.7.3 
| | |     `-- minimalistic-assert@1.0.1 
| | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1 
| | | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1 
| | +-- supports-color@5.4.0 
| | | `-- has-flag@3.0.0 
| | `-- yargs@6.6.0 
| |   +-- camelcase@3.0.0 
| |   +-- cliui@3.2.0 
| |   +-- os-locale@1.4.0 
| |   +-- string-width@1.0.2 
| |   | +-- code-point-at@1.1.0 
| |   | `-- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
| |   |   `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1 
| |   +-- which-module@1.0.0 
| |   `-- yargs-parser@4.2.1 
| +-- webpack-merge@4.1.2 
| +-- webpack-sources@1.1.0 
| | +-- source-list-map@2.0.0 
| | `-- source-map@0.6.1 
| `-- webpack-subresource-integrity@1.0.4 
|   `-- webpack-core@0.6.9 
|     +-- source-list-map@0.1.8 
|     `-- source-map@0.4.4 
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.7
+-- @angular/compiler@4.4.7 
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.7 
| +-- @angular/tsc-wrapped@4.4.7 
| | `-- tsickle@0.21.6 
| |   `-- minimist@1.2.0 
| +-- minimist@1.2.0 
| `-- reflect-metadata@0.1.12 
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.7
+-- @angular/forms@4.4.7 
+-- @angular/http@4.4.7 
+-- @angular/language-service@4.4.7 
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.4.7
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.7
+-- @angular/router@4.4.7 
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @firebase/app@^0.1.6
+-- @types/jasmine@2.5.54 
+-- @types/jasminewd2@2.0.3 
+-- @types/node@6.0.106 
+-- angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6.0 
+-- bootstrap@3.3.7 
+-- codelyzer@3.2.2 
| +-- app-root-path@2.0.1 
| +-- css-selector-tokenizer@0.7.0 
| | +-- cssesc@0.1.0 
| | +-- fastparse@1.1.1 
| | `-- regexpu-core@1.0.0 
| |   +-- regenerate@1.3.3 
| |   +-- regjsgen@0.2.0 
| |   `-- regjsparser@0.1.5 
| |     `-- jsesc@0.5.0 
| +-- cssauron@1.4.0 
| | `-- through@2.3.8 
| +-- semver-dsl@1.0.1 
| +-- source-map@0.5.7 
| `-- sprintf-js@1.0.3 
+-- core-js@2.5.5 
+-- firebase@4.13.1 
| +-- @firebase/app@0.2.0 
| | +-- @firebase/app-types@0.2.0 
| | `-- @firebase/util@0.1.11 
| +-- @firebase/auth@0.4.2 
| | `-- @firebase/auth-types@0.2.1 
| +-- @firebase/database@0.2.2 
| | +-- @firebase/database-types@0.2.1 
| | +-- @firebase/logger@0.1.1 
| | `-- faye-websocket@0.11.1 
| |   `-- websocket-driver@0.7.0 
| |     +-- http-parser-js@0.4.12 
| +-- @firebase/firestore@0.4.1 
| | +-- @firebase/firestore-types@0.3.0 
| | +-- @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.2.8 
| | `-- grpc@1.10.1 
| |   +-- node-pre-gyp@0.7.0 
| |   | +-- detect-libc@1.0.3 
| |   | +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 
| |   | | `-- minimist@0.0.8 
| |   | +-- nopt@4.0.1 
| |   | | +-- abbrev@1.1.1 
| |   | | `-- osenv@0.1.5 
| |   | |   +-- os-homedir@1.0.2 
| |   | |   `-- os-tmpdir@1.0.2 
| |   | +-- npmlog@4.1.2 
| |   | | +-- are-we-there-yet@1.1.4 
| |   | | | `-- delegates@1.0.0 
| |   | | +-- console-control-strings@1.1.0 
| |   | | +-- gauge@2.7.4 
| |   | | | +-- aproba@1.2.0 
| |   | | | +-- has-unicode@2.0.1 
| |   | | | +-- object-assign@4.1.1 
| |   | | | +-- signal-exit@3.0.2 
| |   | | | +-- string-width@1.0.2 
| |   | | | | +-- code-point-at@1.1.0 
| |   | | | | `-- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 
| |   | | | |   `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1 
| |   | | | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1 
| |   | | | | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1 
| |   | | | `-- wide-align@1.1.2 
| |   | | `-- set-blocking@2.0.0 
| |   | +-- rc@1.2.6 
| |   | | +-- deep-extend@0.4.2 
| |   | | +-- ini@1.3.5 
| |   | | +-- minimist@1.2.0 
| |   | | `-- strip-json-comments@2.0.1 
| |   | +-- request@2.83.0 
| |   | | +-- aws-sign2@0.7.0 
| |   | | +-- aws4@1.6.0 
| |   | | +-- caseless@0.12.0 
| |   | | +-- combined-stream@1.0.6 
| |   | | | `-- delayed-stream@1.0.0 
| |   | | +-- extend@3.0.1 
| |   | | +-- forever-agent@0.6.1 
| |   | | +-- form-data@2.3.2 
| |   | | | `-- asynckit@0.4.0 
| |   | | +-- har-validator@5.0.3 
| |   | | | +-- ajv@5.5.2 
| |   | | | | +-- co@4.6.0 
| |   | | | | +-- fast-deep-equal@1.1.0 
| |   | | | | +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0 
| |   | | | | `-- json-schema-traverse@0.3.1 
| |   | | | `-- har-schema@2.0.0 
| |   | | +-- hawk@6.0.2 
| |   | | | +-- boom@4.3.1 
| |   | | | +-- cryptiles@3.1.2 
| |   | | | | `-- boom@5.2.0 
| |   | | | +-- hoek@4.2.1 
| |   | | | `-- sntp@2.1.0 
| |   | | +-- http-signature@1.2.0 
| |   | | | +-- assert-plus@1.0.0 
| |   | | | +-- jsprim@1.4.1 
| |   | | | | +-- extsprintf@1.3.0 
| |   | | | | +-- json-schema@0.2.3 
| |   | | | | `-- verror@1.10.0 
| |   | | | `-- sshpk@1.14.1 
| |   | | |   +-- asn1@0.2.3 
| |   | | |   +-- bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1 
| |   | | |   +-- dashdash@1.14.1 
| |   | | |   +-- ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
| |   | | |   +-- getpass@0.1.7 
| |   | | |   +-- jsbn@0.1.1 
| |   | | |   `-- tweetnacl@0.14.5 
| |   | | +-- is-typedarray@1.0.0 
| |   | | +-- isstream@0.1.2 
| |   | | +-- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
| |   | | +-- mime-types@2.1.18 
| |   | | | `-- mime-db@1.33.0 
| |   | | +-- oauth-sign@0.8.2 
| |   | | +-- performance-now@2.1.0 
| |   | | +-- qs@6.5.1 
| |   | | +-- safe-buffer@5.1.1 
| |   | | +-- stringstream@0.0.5 
| |   | | +-- tough-cookie@2.3.4 
| |   | | | `-- punycode@1.4.1 
| |   | | +-- tunnel-agent@0.6.0 
| |   | | `-- uuid@3.2.1 
| |   | +-- rimraf@2.6.2 
| |   | | `-- glob@7.1.2 
| |   | |   +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0 
| |   | |   +-- inflight@1.0.6 
| |   | |   +-- minimatch@3.0.4 
| |   | |   | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.8 
| |   | |   |   +-- balanced-match@1.0.0 
| |   | |   |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1 
| |   | |   `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1 
| |   | +-- semver@5.5.0 
| |   | +-- tar@2.2.1 
| |   | | +-- block-stream@0.0.9 
| |   | | +-- fstream@1.0.11 
| |   | | | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
| | | +-- isarray@0.0.1 
| | | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31 
| | `-- semver@4.3.6 
| +-- @firebase/functions@0.1.1 
| | +-- @firebase/functions-types@0.1.1 
| | +-- @firebase/messaging-types@0.1.3 
| | `-- isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1 
| |   `-- node-fetch@1.7.3 
| |     +-- encoding@0.1.12 
| |     | `-- iconv-lite@0.4.21 
| |     |   `-- safer-buffer@2.1.2 
| |     `-- is-stream@1.1.0 
| +-- @firebase/messaging@0.2.4 
| +-- @firebase/polyfill@0.3.1 
| | +-- promise-polyfill@7.1.2 
| | `-- whatwg-fetch@2.0.4 
| +-- @firebase/storage@0.1.9 
| | `-- @firebase/storage-types@0.1.3 
| +-- dom-storage@2.1.0 
| `-- xmlhttprequest@1.8.0 
+-- font-awesome@4.7.0 
+-- jasmine-core@2.6.4 
+-- jasmine-spec-reporter@4.1.1 
| `-- colors@1.1.2 
+-- jquery@3.3.1 

##[section]Finishing: install packages via npm
##[section]Starting: build the angular app

[0m[0m
[0mDate: [1m[37m2018-04-29T02:38:26.147Z[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31mERROR in ./src/main.ts[39m[22m[0m
[0mHash: [1m[37mfc0e469a8e1e45ae3fbf[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31mModule not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\a\1\s\src'[39m[22m[0m
[0mTime: [1m[37m13743[39m[22mms[0m
[0m[1m[31mERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module D:/a/1/s/node_modules/angularfire2/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3[39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33mscripts[39m[22m} [1m[32mscripts.d34ccde7090beae870c3.bundle.js[39m[22m (scripts) 148 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25616:34)[39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33m0[39m[22m} [1m[32mpolyfills.0adc185c36444866e853.bundle.js[39m[22m (polyfills) 64.6 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25404:46)[39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33m1[39m[22m} [1m[32mstyles.a114229fe885d968330a.bundle.css[39m[22m (styles) 116 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25385:14)[39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33m2[39m[22m} [1m[32mmain.492b0159584f3ce89c33.bundle.js[39m[22m (main) 434 bytes [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24241:30[39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33m3[39m[22m} [1m[32mvendor.79856e653c3dc17ca7d6.bundle.js[39m[22m (vendor) 208 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at Array.forEach (native)[39m[22m[0m
[0mchunk {[1m[33m4[39m[22m} [1m[32minline.31e1fb380eb7cf3d75b1.bundle.js[39m[22m (inline) 798 bytes [1m[33m[entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at extractProgramSymbols (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24240:79)[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23796:47)[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at CodeGenerator.codegen (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:32:14)[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:73:30)[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31m    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (D:\a\1\s\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:428:58)[39m[22m[0m
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.


    enter code here
```

Comment: pakcage.json:
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "tether": "^1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: On the other hand, try it with angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.3. (remove `^`)

Comment: Starian, I can build the app locally, even managed to push it to Azure using the FTP and everything is wroking fine, but somehow CI doesn't work.

Comment: Do you try it with angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.3? Can you share a sample project on the OneDrive?